# AngularJS midway testing visit function not working

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript

My test suite:

```
describe 'test loading page', ->
  tester = undefined
  beforeEach ->
    if tester then tester.destroy
    tester = ngMidwayTester 'angularjsGettingStartedApp'

  it "should defined dubFuntion and evaluate directive", (done) ->
    tester.visit '/superman' , () ->
      expect(1).toEqual(2) 
      done()
```

Its result

```
Chrome 34.0.1847 (Linux): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 34.0.1847 (Linux): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 34.0.1847 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.182 secs / 0.166 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.046 secs / 0.183 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

Whatever I try it always return SUCCESS -- seem that visit callback haven't called by some reason ??? , I use:

```
"angular": "1.2.15",
"grunt-karma": "^0.8.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
"karma-ng-scenario": "^0.1.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5" done function is missing, but when upgrading to "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0", it work.